# Here's I'm trying to slice a nested list but i'm getting the following output. Explain?

Tags: python-3.5

I've tried the following code but this is giving me a output that i'm unable to predict. Please help me in scanning this code.

```
l=[['d','e','f'],['a','b','c'],2,3,4,5]
l[:2][1:2]
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: Did you look at the output of `l[:2]` first? Do you understand why you get that output? Do you understand what slicing that with `[1:2]` does?

Comment: Here
Your list is

`l=[['d','e','f'],['a','b','c'],2,3,4,5]`

slicing the list as `l[:2]` will return you `0th` and `1st` element as :

`[['d', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]`

and the 2nd slicer `[1:2]` will return you the `1st` from 1st sliced output.

as `[['a', 'b', 'c']]`

Comment: With `l[:2]`, you are selecting the first two elements of the main list, more specifically, the elements 0 (inclusive) to 2 (exclusive); so, you are selecting `[['d','e','f'],['a','b','c']]`.

Over this result, you are selecting `[1:2]`, which means the elements 1 (inclusive) to 2 (exclusive), thus only `[['a', 'b', 'c']]`.

Please, mind that the slicing of lists, in Python, follows the form `start:stop:step`.